# The right event to detect a moving UIElement inside a Canvas

Tags: wpf, events, event-handling, behavior, uielement

I have a `Rectangle` within a `Canvas`. The rectangle has the `MouseDragElementBehavior` attached to it, so it can move freely within the canvas.

I need to do certain calculations when the smallest changes happen in the position of the rectangle, but i can not find a single best event.

So far I have resorted to `MouseMove` event for the rectangle which is an overkill. Any alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should base on the events from MouseDragElementBehaviour class, [DragBegun, DragFinished and Draggging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.expression.interactivity.layout.mousedragelementbehavior_members%28v=expression.40%29.aspx).

Comment: Maybe this link can help http://www.rick-sammons.com/post/Its-out-%28Silverlight-3%29.aspx